# Mocha Chai AssertionError: expected array to be a json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, tdd

1) This first test suite case works well, throw no erros at all.

```
chai.request(app) .get('/api/courses') .end((err, res) => {
res.should.have.status(200);
res.body.should.be.a("json");
done(); });
```

2) Althought, that one says "AssertionError: expected [ Array(3) ] to be a json", even though nothing changed.

```
describe("Courses", () => {
describe("GET /api/courses", () => {
    it("should get all the courses", (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
             .get('/api/courses')
             .end((err, res) => {
                 res.should.have.status(200);
                 res.body.should.be.a("json");
                 done();
              });
    })
});
```

});

I literally just inserted the describe and it features to give more info about the test.

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cjfN.png)

[App.test.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoER4.png)

[Image Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spbrM.png)

Comment: Can you log what res looks like and if err was set?

Comment: Yes, I can! Look the res.body: [ { id: 1, name: 'course1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'course2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'course3' } ]

Comment: That's in both test cases.

Comment: Ok, can you build an standalone proof of concept gist for this? Because if the behaviour you are describing is in fact happening like it is, this would be a chai bug.

Comment: I'll add pictures of the project, it's just two files

Comment: Looking at your code I don't believe that there's anything wrong there. Still, I believe the old, working test you showed wasn't behaving properly. Also in your server, did you try using 'return res.json(courses)' instead of res. send?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fabioqmarsiaj/54f9f985fa77695dc692d12b1ced3a56

Comment: I've tried this 'return res.json(courses), didn't work as well.

Comment: The last commented test is working fine in here

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, what do you want to achieve with this test?

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't want this to be posted as an answer. But while I'm already here:

As far as I can tell, chai is working as expected, since the return value you receive is in fact an array, and not a json (albeit a json-file in NodeJs can be an array). That's why the test is failing. If you want to check the actual header of the response, you can test res.headers. 
Why it was working outside of the mocha test I can not tell you, but feel like it was rather a display- than an actual bug, as in how did you actually test that the assertion was properly validated?

Comment: It's supposed to be a simple test, I'm studying how to use Mocha Chai. I believe the reason is very explicit in it's description.

Comment: Testing routes and etc

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can check whether body is json or not using that command.

```
res.body.should.be.a("json"); // invalid
```

If you take a look at [chai documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_a) or [here](https://github.com/chaijs/type-detect), there is no way you can specify **json** inside `a()` function.

Alternative solution you can check the json from the `res.headers` and also you can check the response body is array or not such as

```
chai
  .request(app)
  .get("/api/courses")
  .end((err, res) => {
    res.should.have.status(200);

    res.body.should.be.a('array'); 
    res.headers["content-type"].should.contains('application/json');

    done();
  });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @FabioQuintoMarsiaj awesome, glad it worked for you!